# How to list S3 objects using Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

It's very simple to list S3 objects in Python with boto3 which only requires AWS_ACCESS_KEY and SECRET in ~/.aws/credentials, but I can't find a simple example in Java to do the same thing.

How can you accomplish the following Python functionality in Java instead?

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name="default")
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket("mybucketname")
for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(my_bucket_object.key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See an example below and also see the AWS docs [example_s3_listobj](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_ListObjects_section.html) page.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectListing;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;

public class ListS3Objects {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create an S3 client using default credentials provider chain
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                                      .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                                      .build();

        String bucketName = "bucketname";

        // Get a list of objects in the specified bucket
        ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(bucketName);

        // Print the object keys
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
            System.out.println(objectSummary.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had toyed with this sample before, but this time I got it working by taking out the quotation marks when I set the credential environment variables in the Edit Configuration page of Intellij

Comment: Understand that this is deprecated code - the Java toolkit is now at version 2.